# Sending credentials with JavaScript XMLHttpRequest is not working

Tags: javascript, android, web-services, cordova

I try to send credentials with an XMLHttprequest like the following:

```
request.open("POST","https://myurl.com",true,"domain\\user","password");
...
```

This is for an Android App using Phonegap. On my mobile it does not even connect to the server when i use "domain\\user". If I only put  "user" in there, without domain,  it works just fine. And in the Browser both ways work out :-(

What am I missing, I am really new to this stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has the same problem: It was because in Android the backslashes are not getting encoded. After I used "encodeURIComponent()" it worked.